# Power Amplifier Bypass Switch Convention?

Tags: amplifier, rf

I have an RF power amplifier (PA) for a transceiver module I'm designing. My transceiver is capable of outputting +14 dBm at the 915 MHz ISM band and the RF PA will be used to further amplify the output to +30 dBm. When not requiring the 1W output power, I would like to use the shutdown mode of the PA.

Would it be possible to have a SPST RF switch with one end connected on the RF input to the PA and the other to its output to *bypass* the PA when shutdown? Will this affect the RF too much (if so, how)?

The other option would be to have two SPDT RF switches to create separate RF paths - except this adds an extra 0.5 dB insertion loss.

[image: RF Switches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bypass the PA, you'll need to have a separate RF path. If you just put the SPST in parallel with the PA, you'll be making a very crude splitter with one path that has gain. This will pretty much kill any isolation you have and you'll basically make a feedback loop.

If you want to bypass the PA, you'll need to do something like you suggested with the SPDT low power path. You can probably find a PA with built in bypassing, honestly.

Now, if you have the PA in shutdown mode such that there is no gain, then the feedback and oscillation is not a problem. However, you'll still have a rather large impedance mismatch if you don't design your circuit correctly. The chip you've linked has a 1.5 VSWR when in shutdown, which means that you'll actually split a lot of your power with the SPST approach. You'll need to create that bypass path.

Comment: This makes sense, I appreciate the explanation. I was going to use the [MAX2235](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2235.pdf) but I do not think bypassing is possible. It is hard to find PA's that go up to +30 dBm.

Comment: Yes, however you could use multiple RF amplifiers and combine them. You would need to fully understand the FCC implications. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: The two components are the [MAX2235](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2235.pdf) and [SKY13453-385LF](http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/SKY13453_385LF_202830C.pdf). The PA says "Standby mode input VSWR Change" is 1.5:1, but if I have the SPDT switches bypassing the PA completely, why do I need a good input/output match to the PA?

Comment: Because you're physically bypassing, you don't need a good match in shutdown mode. There are other applications where a good match in shutdown mode is preferred but outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Understand now, thanks. I thought you meant a good impedance match for the physically bypassed approach - hence my confusion. How did you acquire your RF experience, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: Took an RF job out of college cuz I didn't know better.